# How get list of customer which bought just once (in the last x month) in Magento?

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, customer, reports

How get list of customer which bought just once (in the last x month) in Magento?

**Like:**

bought once in last 12 months

bought once in last 9 months

bought once in last 20 months

bought once in last 36 months

Comment: Bough means donot understand the word?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder
      ->addFilter('status','pending','eq')
      ->addSortOrder($this->sortBuilder->setField('entity_id')
      ->setDescendingDirection()->create())
      ->setPageSize(100)->setCurrentPage(1)->create();

    $to = date("Y-m-d h:i:s"); // current date
    $from = strtotime('-2 day', strtotime($to));
    $from = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', $from); // 2 days before

    $ordersList = $this->orderRepository->getList($searchCriteria);
    $ordersList->addFieldToFilter('created_at', array('from'=>$from, 'to'=>$to));
}
```